# Changing function call from static to dynamic VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that I call multiple times, 14 times minimum, as of now I am statically calling each method and changing each of the variables that have to be entered in the function.

code for function call as of now.

```
If HeaderExists("W_Sheet", "BM") Then 'Checking if function needs to be called
 
    Set rng = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="BM", LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
    prevHeader = ws.ListObjects("W_Sheet").HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, rng.column - 1).Value 'find the previous header to the current one
    
    Call splitColumn(rng.column, "BM", "BM", prevHeader) ' actual calling of the function with parameter passing
  End If
```

Now this particular code will be repeated 14 times,(or as many number of headers are present) with  only the parameters changing.
Is there a way to introduce this in a loop of some kind??

**EDIT**
**Forgive me for not being Clear,**

Points to note

1. Am splitting my table based on the columns thus am checking if a particular header is present or not and based on that I am executing this code.
2. please note the splitcolumn sub does creates new worksheets, and pastes the data there, to ensure sheets dont end up scrambled, I use prevheader to anchor new sheet to old sheet(checking if sheet by prevheader name exists and creating a new sheet on that)

the one scenario this dosent happen is the first sheet, I have hardcoded which sheet, the new one should be anchored to

3. What I would like to happen is as follows

3.1) Code creates an array of all headers in the table

3.2) Code **disregards the first 8 headers**

3.3) Code passes the name of 9th header and the hardcoded sheet name to the function

3.4) from the 10th header onwards, it passes the name of each header(nth) and the previous(n-1)th header to the function.

is this possible to do??

Comment: Your question is not so clear, at least, according to my way of understanding... Do you have list of headers to be checked? I suppose that `HeaderExists` function validates if "BM" exists as a header. What do you like doing, in fact? To parse the header list and the run the code for each of them? What "BM" is? Is it a header, or something else?

Comment: Could you share the code where you use your snippet at least 14 times and of course, the code of the 'function' which is just a `Sub`, not a `Function` since it doesn't return anything?

Comment: And what do you need changing each time? "BM" string? If not, what else? If "BM" can you supply a list of these 14 'things' to be automatically updated?

Comment: Pedantic point: `If HeaderExists("W_Sheet", "BM") = True ` is equivalent to `If HeaderExists("W_Sheet", "BM")` -- there is no reason to compare (what seems to be) a Boolean with a Boolean. It already is a truth value so doesn't need a comparison to turn it into a truth value. Dropping the `= True` makes the code slightly more readable.

Comment: @FaneDuru, my apologies on not being clear on my requirements, I have edited the question please have a look, yes Parsing the headers and running code for each is the main idea.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I didnt understand the requirement, the snippet that uses this code, is the above code written 14 times with changes in the parameters that are passed. Is that what u want?? also ,thanks for telling the difference between sub and function, I didnt know :), I have added info to the question, is this enough?

Comment: Almost everything is possible, if you know how to ask... Is the table in discussion a `ListObject, or just an ordinary sheet you name it "table'? We firstly need to identify on which row the headers in discussion exist. Then, I asked you in clear. Should each the previous mentioned array elements replace the existing "BM"?

Comment: @JohnColeman noted, have edited the code and here too. Thanks for pointing it out. Please look at the edits in the question

Comment: @FaneDuru, the Headers exist in Row 1, the array of headers should replace BM

Comment: OK, now what does "the hardcoded sheet" mean? The name of active sheet where the code works? Then, should it replace "W_Sheet" and the header in the array instead of "BM? If the above supposition is correct, you mentioned about the sheet name only for the 9th header. What to be used for the following ones? Not the same sheet name? Please, also clarify what "*it passes the name of each header(nth) and the previous(n-1)th header to the function*" means. Shouldn't the code provide each header instead of "BM". What previous are you referring to? Try building an example, please.

Comment: What is difference between `ws` sheet and "the hardcoded sheet"? If you answer again after more than half an hour, I will be left from the office, anyhow... But your question is still not clear for anybody, I think.

Comment: @FaneDuru, so for ease I have been naming my sheets after my headers, `code: Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(prevSheet)).Name = colHeader`  now for the 9th header I have to give the name `"Sheet1"` but for all other headers I will stick with `prevSheet`   _For the last part_  `splitColumn(rng.column, nth header, nth header, (n-1)th header)`  does this make it less murky??

Comment: This comment brought some light, but still darkness... What should the code use instead of existing `If HeaderExists("W_Sheet", "BM")`? Change only "BM" with the header and "W_Sheet" remains as it is?

Comment: @FaneDuru, `ws Sheet` is the active Sheet, `hardcoded sheet-> aka Sheet1`  is the data sheet

Comment: `If HeaderExists("W_Sheet", Headerarray)` this should work,

Comment: `"aka Sheet1"` should be the sheet name to be used firstly? in the 9th header case? Is `ws` the active sheet?

Comment: Yes @FaneDuru, sheet1 to be used first, in the 9th header case, ws is active sheet

Comment: "Sheet1`" or "aka Sheet1"?

Comment: Please, try the code I posted. It will fill "Sheet1" in the `Sub` call...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub testIteration()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastCol As Long, rngH As Range, arrH, El, count As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
    lastCol = ws.cells(1, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column

    arrH = ws.Range(ws.cells(1, 9), ws.cells(1, lastCol)).Value
    For Each El In arrH
         count = count + 1
         If headerExists("W_Sheet", CStr(El)) Then 'Checking if function needs to be called
            Call SplitColumn(count + 8, El, El, IIf(count = 1, "Sheet1", arrH(1, count - 1))) ' actual calling of the function with parameter passing
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting a Subscript out of range error, at the function call `Call SplitColumn()` more specifically , here ->`arrH(1, I - 1)` `I is empty` This is during the initial run of the code, `E1 is still "BM"`, it hasent proceeded further

Comment: @Allwyn P  It should be `count -1`. Please, try the updated code.

Comment: just a small edit its `arrH(1,count)`. The code works wonderfully. Thanks for introducing me to `CStr and IIF` beautiful functions and works so well with my code.

Comment: @Allwyn P Glad I (finally) could help. But it looks I still did not understand your question completely... `count -1` should return the previous array element, which in my understanding should be the previous header. In fact, I think I can understand now when writing... Your previous way was based on finding of the header, which was named as `prevHeader`. Not needing it, this `prevHeader`, which was not really a previous header, I didn't reflexively realize that it should be, in fact, the actual one.

Comment: :D Glad we cleared this out.. @FaneDuru,  I have one more active question in Stack, could you please look at this?   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68845324/color-pivot-table-data-depending-on-row-column-data-values-vba)

Comment: @@Allwyn P I will take a look now.

Answer (score 0):

There are some details lacking, so some guesses below.
With a loop like this

```
    For Each ColName In Array("BM", "AB", "XY", "XZ")
        ' Your logic goes here
    Next
```

you can run it once per entry in the array. Put your code inside the for loop and replace every `"BM"` with `ColName`

Comment: Hi @Sam, thanks for the answer, please look at the edits in the question, is there a way to include all the conditions to your code???