# Color Pivot Table data depending on row, column & data values VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro, that dynamically generates n number of pivot tables.
I am trying to code to ensure that pivot tables that meet a specific set of conditions are highlighted.

My conditions are as follows

1. all Values that fall in the Row online and are equal to 2 days (in one color "Orange")
2. all Values that fall in the Row online and are greater than 2 days (in one color "Red")
3. all cells that are under any header greater than 5 days (in another color "Yellow")
4. any time the headers are 5 days or more, then the headers themselves are highlighted in "Yellow"

The code for the same are as follows.

```
Sub conditionalFormatingPivotTable(ByVal Worksheet As String)

Dim pt As PivotTable, pf As PivotField, pi As PivotItem, d
Dim rngTwoDays As Range, rngFiveDays As Range, rwOnline As Range, c As Range

Set pt = Worksheets("Summary").PivotTables(Worksheet & "PivotTable") 'Setting the pivot table
pt.TableRange1.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'Removing any kind of highlighting that exists


'Start coloring

' x days labels >=5days
Set pf = pt.PivotFields(Worksheet)
For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
    d = Val(pi.Name) 'days number only
    If d >= 5 Then pi.LabelRange.Resize(2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    If d = 5 Then Set rngFiveDays = pi.DataRange 'for next block
    If d = 2 Then Set rngTwoDays = pi.DataRange  'for next block
Next pi

'the rest
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Order Category")
For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
    If pi.Name = "Online" Then
        For Each c In pi.DataRange.Cells
            If c.Value > 0 And c.column >= rngTwoDays.column Then
                If Not Application.Intersect(c, rngTwoDays) Is Nothing Then
                    c.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbOrange
                Else
                    c.Interior.Color = vbRed
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    Else ' will highlight all other Order categories ("Stock & Store")
        For Each c In pi.DataRange.Cells
            If c.Value > 0 And c.column >= rngFiveDays.column Then
                c.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
        Next c
    End If
Next pi

End Sub
```

Issue is that when I run the code, some of my PIVOT TABLEs (PT's) are highlighted (where conditions are met)
whereas others don't get highlighted even though they meet the condition.

in the below example the pivot in btw got highlighted correctly, whereas the top and bottom PT's missed out on the stock data highlighting

Please help in figuring out where the error is.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It basically, use a different algorithm to set `rngFiveDays` range and created condition to skip checking of nothing object column:

```
Function conditionalFormatingPivotTable(ByVal Worksheet As String)
    Dim pt As PivotTable, pf As PivotField, pi As PivotItem, d
    Dim rngTwoDays As Range, rngFiveDays As Range, rwOnline As Range, c As Range
    
    Set pt = Worksheets("Summary").PivotTables(Worksheet & "PivotTable")
    pt.TableRange1.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'uncolor
    
    ' x days labels >=5days
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields(Worksheet)
    Set rngFiveDays = Nothing
    For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        d = Val(pi.Name) 'days number only
        If d >= 5 Then
            pi.LabelRange.Resize(2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            If rngFiveDays Is Nothing Then Set rngFiveDays = pi.DataRange
        End If
        If d = 2 Then Set rngTwoDays = pi.DataRange  'for next block
    Next pi
    
    'the rest
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Order Category")
    For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        If pi.Name = "Online" Then
            For Each c In pi.DataRange.Cells
                If Not rngTwoDays Is Nothing Then '!!!!
                    If c.Value > 0 And c.column >= rngTwoDays.column Then
                        If Not Application.Intersect(c, rngTwoDays) Is Nothing Then
                            c.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbOrange
                        Else
                            c.Interior.Color = vbRed
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next c
        Else
            For Each c In pi.DataRange.Cells
                If Not rngFiveDays Is Nothing Then '!!!
                    If c.Value > 0 And c.column >= rngFiveDays.column Then
                        c.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    End If
                End If
            Next c
        End If
    Next pi
End Function
```

I could see your `SortPT` function which uses a big manually created array. Like a bonus, please try using the next function, able to automatically create it, according to the interval you set:

Existing array:

```
rngSort = Array("1 day", "2 days", "3 days", "4 days", "5 days", "6 days", "7 days", "8 days", _
    "9 days", "10 days", "11 days", "12 days", "13 days", "14 days", "15 days", "16 days", "17 days", _
    "18 days", "19 days", "20 days", "21 days", "22 days", "23 days", "24 days", "25 days", "26 days", _
    "27 days", "28 days", "29 days", "30 days", "31 days", "32 days", "33 days", "34 days", "35 days", _
    "36 days", "37 days", "38 days", "39 days", "40 days", "41 days", "42 days", "43 days", "44 days", "45 days")
```

The function to automatically create it:

```
Function arrDays(interv As String) As Variant
     Dim arr, frstEl As String
     arr = Split(Replace(interv, " ", ""), "-"): interv = arr(0) + 1 & ":" & arr(1)
     frstEl = IIf(arr(0) = "1", "1 day,", arr(0) & " days,")
     arrDays = Split(frstEl & Join(Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(" & interv & "))"), " days,") & " days", ",")
End Function
```

It can be tested in the next way:

```
Sub testArrDays()
   Dim rngSort, interval As String
   interval = "2-45"
   'interval = "2 - 25" 'just for testing that it works so, too
   rngSort = arrDays(interval)
   Debug.Print Join(rngSort, "|")
End Sub
```

Not knowing very well all the issued pivot tables peculiarities, I would suggest you to analyze if it is not possible to have cases without "2 days", but to be necessary similar formatting in case of "3 days" existance. Just a thought...

Comment: one small doubt, I am trying the simplest of things, autofill,  but somehow I am jumping from error to error. Could u please look at this line `ws.Range(ws.Cells(emptyCell + 1, 2).Address).AutoFill Destination:=Range((ws.Cells(emptyCell + 1, 2).Address) & Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row), Type:=xlFillDefault`   empty cell contains the value for first empty cell  in the column,   Source and Destination starting addresses are the same, yet  its bugging out.   error is `Range of Object_Global failed`  any clues on why this is happening?

Comment: @Allwyn P I will be able to suggest a correction if I would understand what you want accomplishing... Do you want copying from the first row following an empty cell in B:B, up to the last cell in column A:A? Or what? Only looking to your code, I am not able to understand what you try doing... How the Source and Destination to be the same?

Comment: @Allwyn I only suppose that you need to autofill **only** on column B:B, but up to the last row in A:A. If so, please try: `ws.cells(emptycell + 1, 2).AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range(ws.cells(emptycell + 1, 2), ws.cells(ws.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row, 2)), Type:=xlFillDefault`. If not, please better clarify what you try accomplishing (in words...).

Comment: @Allwyn Besides all that, I would like to tell you that such issues should mean a new question. If I will not be available, somebody else will clarify the issue... But, please focus on better explaining of what you try doing. It is difficult to deduce something from a non working code...

Comment: 1) I have added a formula to a cell in a table Column B (the last cell in a column), am trying to fill the rest of the columns with the same formula, so am using the autofill function. & I am referencing column A to know the length until autofill has to run. 2) I am modifying this code `.Range("C2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C" & Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row)` to suite my needs  3) what I have understood of autofill formula is that we have to have same cell in source `Range("C2")` and in destination also `Range("C2:C` else it will bug out.

Comment: @Allwyn Besides If so, didn't my above suggestion solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it did, sorry didnt notice the middle message.. :)

Comment: One doubt, for last 6 days I have used the code, there was no issues, but today its throwing an error for` Object Variable or With Block variable not set` I have tried adding the with block to the code, but its still throwing the same error, I had not changed anything in the code.. any idea why its happening??? pasting the same code as an with the error . Please check it out

Comment: @Allwyn Besides I may have an idea only if you show me **on which code line** this error is raised. The code is complex and even if I have some imagination, I cannot say anything in these circumstances. In such a situation, I can only guess that the problem I warned you about maybe hits now. The range for two days definition does not exist and the code tries checking it. But I would like to state that I am not a mind reader...

Comment: Sorry I meant to say, I have pasted the error code as an answer, with a comment on which line the error is happening

Comment: Am really sorry, @FaneDuru I am trying to communicate exactly what the issue is, please forgive the stumbles

Comment: @Allwyn P Placing such a pseudo answer is forbidden. It will be voted down and finally deleted. Please, delete it and try doing what I recommended.

Comment: `If c.Value > 0 And c.Column >= rngTwoDays.Column Then` <- error happens here

Comment: @Allwyn P Exactly the issue I imagined and I tried preventing you about it... When stopped on error, if move the cursor over `rngTwoDays`, it probably shows `nothing`. In my above answer I said **I would suggest you to analyze if it is not possible to have cases without "2 days", but to be necessary similar formatting in case of "3 days" existence**. In the file I you sent to me, it was not the case. Now, it looks that it is. So, analyze the situation and let me know what problem exists in that specific table, **where the code stops**. If not able to determine it, send the workbook to me.

Comment: @Allwyn P But send it only **after you tried understanding what happens**...

Comment: I have a doubt, This time, there is 16 pivot tables that are being made, `first 8 pivots were made correctly`, no issues at all, `9th & 10th the condition "online" wasn't triggered`, and  `10th to 14th were made correctly` for the '15th pivot,  the error  message was triggered' now its the same value that gets checked for every condition, and all are being generated dynamically.

Comment: @Allwyn  I am afraid I cannot get you... I do not care about the tables processed well. Try focusing only **on the problematic one**. Doesn't it have "2 days" between "Worksheet" pivot fields, but it has something more, like "3 days", "4 days", as I presume? If yes, what would you like the code to do? To make yellow the following grater value, or to skip that code part if `rngTwoDays` is nothing? If not this is the case, please better explain what is it about. But you should try following my above suggestions/assumptions...

Comment: IT WORKED.. Your suggestion worked.. what I  added was the following 'If Not rngFiveDays Is Nothing Or Not rngTwoDays Is Nothing Then '!!! new code '4'  Now the code runs without issues.. Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction..  You are a very good mentor.  5 hrs well spent